# Calculate time interval excluding breaks

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I have a solution for [a question I asked on SO](//stackoverflow.com/q/70666387):

> I am trying to create a database where I also need to find the time
> difference inside a record. However, `timediff()` does not give the
> result I need. What I mean is that there are 3 fixed time intervals in
> every day and each record stores `time_1` & `time_2` datetime entries.
>
> My question is, for example, if `time_1='2020-01-01 04:30'` and `time_2= '2020-01-08 15:45'` of a single record is given, then how is it
> possible to find exact time difference in that record?
>
> For simplicity, we can assume that `fixedtime1` is the interval 5:00 and
> 6:00, `fixedtime2` is the interval 13:00 and 14:00 and `fixedtime3` is the
> interval 21:00 and 22:00.  You can calculate it inside your head easily
> for the record obtained.

```
drop    table   if  exists  testtable;
create  table   TestTable(
id  int primary key,
time_1  datetime    not null,
time_2  datetime    not null,
textbox text);
insert  into    testtable(id,time_1,time_2)
values
(1,'2020-01-01  04:30','2020-01-08  15:45'),    /*exact =   9420    */  
(2,'2021-05-06  16:55','2021-07-01  23:15'),    /*exact =   70880   */  
(3,'2021-12-30  19:55','2022-01-02  03:10'),    /*exact =   2955 */ 
(4,'2021-12-31  23:59','2022-01-01  05:14'),    /*exact =   255  */ 
(5,'2022-01-01  01:01','2021-01-01  01:30'),    /*exact =   29  */  
(6,'2021-01-01  23:20','2021-01-02  00:10');


set @breakst1 = '03:45:00';
set @breakend1 =    '04:45:00';
set @breakst2 = '12:00:00';
set @breakend2 =    '13:00:00';
set @breakst3 = '18:00:00';
set @breakend3 =    '19:00:00';

select 

(case   when    time(time_1) between @breakst1 and @breakend1                                                   /*time_to_sec(timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1)," ",@breakst1)))/60   between 0 and 60    then    0   old*/
                then    0                                       
                when    time(time_1) between @breakend1 and @breakst2                                                   /*time_to_sec(timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1)," ",@breakst1)))/60   between 60 and 495      old*/
                THEN    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1))
                                                                                            )/60-60)
                WHEN    time(time_1) between @breakst2 and @breakend2                                                   /*brand new*/
                THEN    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1))
                                                                                            )/60-60)+
                        time_to_sec(timediff(time(time_1),@breakst2))/60                                                /*brand new*/
                WHEN    time(time_1) between @breakend2 and @breakst3           /*new*/                                 /*time_to_sec(timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1)," ",@breakst1)))/60   between 495 and 855     old*/
                THEN    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1))
                                                                                            )/60-120)
                WHEN    time(time_1) between @breakst3 and @breakend3                                                   /*brand new*/
                THEN    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1))
                                                                                            )/60-120)+
                        time_to_sec(timediff(time(time_1),@breakst3))/60                                                /*brand new*/
                WHEN    time(time_1) between @breakend3 and '23:59:59'          /*new*/                                 /*time_to_sec(timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1)," ",@breakst1)))/60   between 855 AND 1214    old*/
                THEN    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1))
                                                                                            )/60-180)
                
                else    
                        abs(time_to_sec(timediff(time_1,concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakst1)))/60)  
        end)    
        
       as pt1,  /*you can replace this part without "as pt1,"  and you will get sum*/
                
        (case   when    time(time_2) between '00:00:00' and @breakst1           /*new*/                                 /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between -285 and -60    old*/
                then    
                        -abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60+60)
                when    time(time_2) between @breakst1 and @breakend1           /*new*/                                 /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between -60 and 0   then    0   old*/
                then    0
                when    time(time_2) between @breakend1 and @breakst2           /*new*/                                 /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between 0 and   435 old*/
                then    
                        abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60)
                when    time(time_2) between @breakst2 and @breakend2                                                   /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between 435 and 495 then    435 old*/
                THEN    
                        abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60)-
                        time_to_sec(timediff(time(time_2),@breakst2))/60                                                /*BRAND NEW*/
                when    time(time_2) between @breakend2 and @breakst3           /*new*/                                 /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between 495 and 795 OLD*/
                then    
                        abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60-60)
                when    time(time_2) between @breakst3 and @breakend3           /*new*/                                 /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between 795 and 855 then    735 OLD*/
                THEN    
                        (abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60-60)-
                        time_to_sec(timediff(time(time_2),@breakst3))/60)                                               /*brand new*/
                when    time(time_2) between @breakend3 and '23:59:59'      /*new*/                                     /*(time_to_sec(timediff(concat(date(time_1),"   ",time(time_2)),concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1)))/60) between 855 and 1154    OLD*/
                then    
                        abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                                concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60-120)
                else    
                        abs(time_to_sec(
                                        timediff(concat(date(time_1),"  ",time(time_2)),
                                        concat(date(time_1),"   ",@breakend1))
                                        )/60-60)    
        end)    as pt2, /*you can replace this part without "as pt2,"  and you will get sum*/
                
       (case when time(time_2)>time(time_1) 
                then
                    case    when    time_to_sec(timediff(time_2,time_1))/60<1260    then    0
                    else    datediff(time_2,time_1)*1260    
                    end
            when time(time_1)>=time(time_2) then    datediff(time_2,time_1)*1260
        else 'error_final_step'
        end) as pt3
from testtable
```

Edit: İ revised code and now it works as intended without any mistakes so far.
now it calculates 3 things and the result is sum of pt1,pt2 and pt3

Comment: Note that some RDBMS will spit this out, because `#` is not a comment in SQL; `--` is.

Comment: This solution looks terribly complex. With a few corrections [I am able run your code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sxqqq744s7AeCB92tSbzdK/0), but I am absolutely not sure the results are not correct. Are you working with minutes? Why?! There's no explanation of the code at all. I would also put the breaks in a database table.

Comment: Yeah i know and it references the the only 1 breakvalue rather than using it all. And my question explains the problem and struggles i have been through to calculate it. My real problem is convert this piece of complexity into simplier and more understandable code. I am using MySQL WB  InnoDB latest version as of now. And # or /**/ comments my notes. If i get to find time, i will rewrite the whole thing. I am quitte busy with reporting stuff since new year and other sorts of things.idea came up to find a better solution to tracking stop start times and time loss calculations as a side project.

Comment: Where does "495" come from?  What is special about that number (and all the other constants other then "60"?

Comment: 495 is the time difference between end of the break and start of another in minutes. I actually rewrote the entire code but since i am not using my own laptop for a while i wasnt able to upload newer one. If i get a chance, will do it

Comment: Hi. I just edited code and new version(?) is up and i think it is much versatile now.